# Scala type inference not working with play json

Tags: scala, playframework, type-inference, implicit

I am writing an http client and this is my signature:

```scala
def post[Req, Resp](json: Req)(implicit r: Reads[Resp], w: Writes[Req]): Future[Resp]
```

Using play json behind the scenes.

When I use it like this

```scala
def create(req: ClusterCreateRequest): Future[ClusterCreateResponse] = endpoint.post(req)
```

I get the following error

```
diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[Resp]
```

The following works

```scala
def create(req: ClusterCreateRequest): Future[ClusterCreateResponse] = endpoint.post[ClusterCreateRequest, ClusterCreateResponse](req)
```

Why is type inference not working as expected? What can I do for this?

Comment: Have you tried if adding of `(implicit r: Reads[Resp], w: Writes[Req])` to the `create` signature works for your case?

Comment: Probably without explicit type parameters some type is inferred to be `Nothing`. And trying to resolve instance of a type class for `Nothing` leads to "diverging implicit expansion".

Answer (score -1):

`diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[Resp]`
means that Resp has few JSON serializers that are not shadowed one by another.

It's not possible to pinpoint root cause the issue and say fix `X` and everything will work from the infrmation given in post.

But you can try to "debug" implicit search. Consider checking the implicit search order: 
[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicitsAlso) Enabling implicit parameter expansion in idea might help to check which implicits(Ctrl+Shift+=) cause a clash.

General advice for type class instances - hold them organized and declared, put them to companion object or to specially dedicated object.

Comment: *"`diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[Resp]` means that Resp has few JSON serializers that are not shadowed one by another."* I guess this is incorrect. Having few serializers would cause "ambiguous implicit values" error, not "diverging implicit expansion" error.